# PHP: Sorting MySQL result to multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Now I'm tryin' to sort MySQL result to multi-dimensional array by `type` line in SQL
so, that's my code:

```
function getTableValues($table_name)
{
//    $link = connect_db();
    $front_end_query = "SELECT * FROM `".$table_name."` WHERE  `type` =  'front_end'";
    $front_end_query_result = mysql_query($front_end_query);

    $cur_row = 0;   
    /*while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) 
    {
        $values = $line;
        $cur_row++;
    }*/
    $front_end = mysql_fetch_assoc($front_end_query_result);
    $i=0;
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($front_end_query_result)){
        #if ($line['type'] === 'front_end'){
        #    $line[$line['type']][$line['name']] = $line['value'];
        #    $line[$line['type']][$line['name']]['desc'] = $line['description'];
        #    $line[$line['type']][$line['name']]['visible_name'] = $line['visible_name'];
        #    $line[$line['type']][$line['name']]['write_roles'] = $line['write_roles'];
        #    $line[$line['type']][$line['name']]['read_roles'] = $line['read_roles'];
        #}

        $values['front_end'][$line['name']] = $line;
        $i++;
    }

    return $values;
}
```

And my MySQL table:

```
id type      write_roles read_roles name        value     description      visible_name     
1  front_end 0           any        title       sometitle exampletitle     Title     
2  front_end 0           any        description somedesc  example          Description
```

And that's what I want to get:

```
$config[(someType)][(SomeName)] = (value of line)
$config[(someType)][(SomeName)][(SomeOption)] = (value of option)
```

E.g.: `$config['front_end']['title']['description']` that returns `exampletitle`

How I can do that?

**UPD0:** so I tried to `echo` my array with `foreach`, and it's returned *just one row* from my DB.
What I doing wrong?

Comment: You're only getting one row because you're calling `mysql_fetch_assoc($front_end_query_result)` before the `while()` which is taking the out the first row. Remove that and you'll get your two rows.

Comment: @Samsquanch I'm commented `while()` before testing

Comment: If you comment out the while then you're only going to get one result. That's what the while is for. `mysql_fetch_assoc` only returns one result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$values = array(); //base array
while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($front_end_query_result)){ //fetch the rows
    //in the base array create a new array under 'name'
    $values[$line['name']] = array(); 
    //for each item in the result set, add it to the new array
    foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
        $values[$line['name']][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't get it
where I defining `$someResult` and `$someIdentifier`?

Comment: Sorry, was just showing the general pattern of how to make a multidimensional array in `php`. Use the second form for your specific case. I will edit my answer as well to clarify.

Comment: ok, but I don't see where I need to define `$someValue`. sorry, but I really can't understand your example.